# Why is this <script> tag being executed but cannot be seen in Fiddler

Tags: javascript, html, fiddler

I am puzzled by the fact that this script tag:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/js/button.df1da1fef194d8f8f3fd803a219a8177.js>
</script>
</head>
```

can be seen using Google inspect after the html page has loaded, but doesn't appear in Fiddler when I examine the same returned html.  Is there something 'special' about the tag?  Am I missing something?  The 'twitter' script IS executed because I can see its execution later on in Fiddler, but why can't I see it in the

```
<head>
```

tag in Fiddler?  When 'async' scripts are executed are they 'removed' from the html automatically?

Comment: The Chrome inspector shows the DOM, wheras Fiddler will show the original HTML. If you look at "View source" in Chrome you'll see the same HTML as Fiddler. Remember, scripts can manipulate the DOM after the document is loaded.

Comment: By "Executed" do you mean fetched (as in HTTP request), or do you mean that it's not in the HTML source at all? If you don't see the request in Fiddler, it might be that Chrome has already cached that resource and is not sending another request for it.

Comment: Yes, 'executed' as in a HttpClient request.  I can see it in Fiddler and I can see the page source in Chrome and yes they match perfectly.  (I thought about Chrome caching so I purged everything before the last test, so I'm pretty sure the cache is empty)

Comment: From what Dai has said, methinks that must be the case, i.e. the 'twitter' <script> tag ISN'T in the download html, but some other <script> within the html is creating the 'twitter' <script> afterwards.  So I'm not missing anything in Fiddler, I'm just not looking far enough down the microscope ...

Answer (score -2):

Dai has pinpointed the sequence of events which must be occurring